# How to assign `value` prop and `v-model` prop to custom Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to create a custom Vue component for a "radio div" -- a div (with a slot for including any content I want) that acts like a radio button so you can select it and only one can be selected among multiple with the same name.

In general radio buttons in VueJS look like so:

```html
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value" v-model="variable" />
```

So I wanted a similar API:

```html
<div-radio name="name" value="value" v-model="variable" />
```

However when I looked up [how to add v-model support to custom component](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-v-model-support-to-custom-vue-js-components) the first link I found on Google claimed:

> For `input` elements, you might use `v-model` like this:
>
> ```html
> <input v-model="email" />
> ```
>
> `v-model` translates to this:
>
> ```html
> <input :value="email" @input="e => email = e.target.value" />
> ```

If `v-model` translates to `:value` and `@input` then it doesn't seem possible to have a prop called "value" at the same time as "v-model" - despite the fact this is how normal VueJS radio buttons work

Am I misunderstanding how `v-model` works? Or is there an alternate solution? Or is what I want just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue allows configuring `v-model`'s `prop` name and `event` name through the component's [`model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#model) option:

> ### `model`
>
> > **New in 2.2.0**
>
> **Type:** `{ prop?: string, event?: string }`
>
> **Details:**
>
> Allows a custom component to customize the prop and event used when it’s used with `v-model`. By default, `v-model` on a component uses `value` as the prop and `input` as the event, but some input types such as checkboxes and radio buttons may want to use the `value` prop for a different purpose. Using the `model` option can avoid the conflict in such cases.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```js
> Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
>   model: {
>     prop: 'checked',
>     event: 'change'
>   },
>   props: {
>     // this allows using the `value` prop for a different purpose
>     value: String,
>     // use `checked` as the prop which take the place of `value`
>     checked: {
>       type: Number,
>       default: 0
>     }
>   },
>   // ...
> })
> ```
>
> ```html
> <my-checkbox v-model="foo" value="some value"></my-checkbox>
> ```
>
> The above will be equivalent to:
>
> ```html
> <my-checkbox
>   :checked="foo"
>   @change="val => { foo = val }"
>   value="some value">
> </my-checkbox>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To use v-model you need to handle value and @input manually:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <input type="radio" :name="name" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" />
 </div
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  name: 'div-radio',
  props:{
    value: Boolean,
    name: String
  }
 }
</script>
```

In a host component, treat it as a normal component:

```
...
<div-radio name="name" v-model="variable1" />
<div-radio name="name" v-model="variable2" />
...
```